# ES6 import - aliasing a string member?

Tags: javascript, import, ecmascript-6

I'm just double-checking that the following is not valid syntax as an ES6 import:

```
import { 'stream/streamItem.html' as StreamItemTemplate } from 'common/templates';
```

I'd really prefer to write it that way as opposed to something like:

```
import { stream_streamItem_html as StreamItemTemplate } from 'common/template';
```

but it appears that strings are not valid member declarations even when aliasing?

Comment: How are you exporting something like that to begin with? ES6 exports only support identifiers, and you can only import identifiers.

Comment: I'm using LoDash's template pre-compilation capabilities to generate a file. It's valid syntax for it to say "exports["stream/streamItem.html"] = {}", apparently!

Comment: @SeanAnderson: that's not an ES6 export though. You should just export as `StreamItemTemplate`

Comment: Then I would run the risk of having naming collisions if two templates had the same name, but were located in different folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-imports), `stream_streamItem_html` in your example is an `IdentifierName`. An `IdentifierName` is, according to the [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-names-and-keywords), (cite) "interpreted according to the Default Identifier Syntax", which means StringLiterals are not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

The standar requires an IdentifierName not a StringLiteral:

> ImportSpecifier :
>
> ImportedBinding
>
> IdentifierName **as** ImportedBinding

http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-imports